# PHP string to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, string

I am trying to copy the string

```
 $str = '
         this
         is
         my
         string';
```

to a JavaScript variable like so

```
 var str1 = '<?php echo $str ?>';
```

but when I do, I get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

If you are asking yourself why I'm doing this,
I create a `<table>` with PHP and insert it to the `$str` variable and want to later use it in a JavaScript function.

Comment: Whenever, you need to place a string available in a PHP variable in a JavaScript code generated by the PHP, you should use json_encode() function. For your example: `var str1 = <?php echo json_encode($str) ?>;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use `json_encode()` from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Example:

```
var str1 = <?php echo json_encode($str) ?>;
```

It takes care of converting newlines to `\n`, escaping any other special characters as necessary, preserve spaces, etc.

Example output for your string:

```
var str1 = "\n         this\n         is\n         my\n         string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is EOL character in your PHP strng.

Use it like this (after replacing all EOL characters with a space):

```
var str1 = '<?php echo str_replace("\n", " ", $str) ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not except multiline strings. You can put a backslash before the end of each line if you want to keep it looking like that.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't like multiline string literals or have a here-doc syntax. Try changing your string to

```
$str = ' \
         this \
         is \
         my \
         string';
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
var str1 = '<?php echo $str; ?>';
```

Notice the semicolon.

Comment: Semicolon is not necessary there.

Comment: What will happen if `$str = "'fail'"` ?